# activar input con JQuery al seleccionar un Checkbox

Tags: jquery, html5

espero que me puedan ayudar que estoy un poco perdido.

Estoy con un formulario con HTML, PHP y JQuery y estoy intentando activar el input asociado a un checkbox cuando seleccionamos dicho checkbox

HTML

```
<section>
              <p id="zona_especie">-</p>
              <div class="form-group wd-xs-600">
                <label class="form-control-label">Specie: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
                <div id="myDiv_especie"></div>
                <input type="hidden" name="especie_seleccionada" id="especie_seleccionada">

              </div><!-- form-group -->
            </section>
```

El JQuery que intento hacer para que cuando se selecciona un checkbox es:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var array3 = json_especies;
   var myDiv3 = document.getElementById("myDiv_especie");
    // Species List
    var table_rdb_list = document.createElement("table");
    table_rdb_list.setAttribute("id", "especiesList");

    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    //Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {

        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");

        var radioList = document.createElement("input");
        radioList.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        radioList.setAttribute('id', 'especie' + i);
        radioList.setAttribute('name', 'especie');
        radioList.setAttribute('value', array3[i].id);
        //radioList.setAttribute('onChange', 'GetCheckedVal()');
        radioList.setAttribute('onClick', 'desactivar()');
        radioList.onchange = function() {
            GetCheckedVal();

        }
        radioList.onClick = function() {
            alert('funcion desactivar');
            desactivar();
        }


        function desactivar(param) {
            alert('entra funcion desactivar');
            var el = document.getElementById('especie' + i);
            el.setAttribute("disabled", "");
            if (param) {
                el.removeAttribute("disabled");
            }
        }



        //radioList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
        var lbl = document.createElement("label");
        lbl.setAttribute("for", "especie" + i);
        lbl.setAttribute("class", "ckbox ckbox-success pos-left-10");

        var t = document.createTextNode(array3[i].nombre + '/' + array3[i].cientifico);


        var numSpecies = document.createElement("input");
        numSpecies.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        numSpecies.setAttribute('id', 'cantSpecies' + i);
        numSpecies.setAttribute('name', 'cantSpecies');
        numSpecies.setAttribute("class", "cantEspecies");
        numSpecies.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');


        lbl.appendChild(t);
        td.appendChild(radioList);
        td.appendChild(lbl);
        td.appendChild(numSpecies);
        tr.appendChild(td);
        tbody.appendChild(tr);

    }
}
```

Pero cuando selecciono un checkbox de la lista que me aparece, no se me activa ningún input.

Sin embargo, si creo el checkbox directamente en el HTML con si id propio etc..., en el onClick o el onChange del checkbox donde hago la llamada a la función, me funciona correctamente.

Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal para que no me reconozca la función cuando genero la lista a través de JQuery?

Muchas gracias

Comment: en la consola me aparece este error `setup_system.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: desactivar is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (setup_system.php:1)`

Comment: Ya lo solucioné y ya me funciona, saqué la función desactivar fuera del **document.ready** junto con la llamada a la variable **array3** y ya me funciono, me activa y desactiva los input al seleccionar un checkbox

Answer (score 1):

revise tú código y la razón por la cual te da el error es porque cuando mandas a llamar la función `desactivar()` lo controlas con un el indice `i` y este después de ejecutar tu código queda con el valor de la ultima iteración del `for` es decir si tienes 2 elementos cuando se ejecuta la función `descativar()` este tiene el valor 2 y no el valor `i` que corresponde al `checkbox` creado dinámicamente lo que te sugiero que cambies un par de lineas :

```
radioList.setAttribute('onClick', 'desactivar()');
```

por

```
radioList.setAttribute('onClick', 'desactivar('+i+')');
```

y en la definición de la función utiliza el parámetro `param` en vez de `i`

```
        function desactivar(param) {
        alert('entra funcion desactivar');
        var el = document.getElementById('especie' + param);
        el.setAttribute("disabled", "");
        if (param) {
            el.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    }
```